# Mock up projects for portfolio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently searching for entry level web development employment and I created a website where I included my mock up projects so that potential employers can see it. However, I want to know if this is allowed? For example, I recreated a website with my own twist and it has the original logo and all. Am I allowed to do this? Also, any tips on what to include on my online portfolio would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you redesigned an already existing website and want to use your redesign in your portfolio for potential employment. If that's the case, there's nothing wrong with that. Just make sure you're able to explain why you made the changes and why your version is better than the original.